# What is the use case scenario for interface type method which return type is same name where its belongs to?

Tags: java, design-patterns, methods, interface

I have seen somewhere while reviewing a code pieces but i had no chance to ask the use cases and I couldn't figure out how this interface will be implemented.When you override the method **A()** then you should return someting that implements **Feature**.Example below,

```
 public interface Feature
 {  
        public Feature A(); 
 }
```

Any advice would be greate. Thanks in advance..

Comment: It's common for `Builder` pattern implementations. Can't give a code example (am on mobile), but I'm sure you'll find it online.

Comment: All sorts of things; factories, builders, anything where you need to access the interface implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
public class MyClass implements Feature {

  public Feature A() {
    //do stuff
    return this; //since MyClass implements Feature we could return this
  }
}
```

As mentioned by @daniu this could be used for method chaining. You could check code for `StringBuilder`. Because of `append(String s)` returning instance of `StringBuilder` you could do this

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("Hello").append(" ").append("world");
```

instead of the following code if `apeend()` returned `void`

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("Hello");
sb.append(" ");
sb.append("world");
```